# Spring Data REST - Failed to Lazily Load collection

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, hateoas, spring-data-rest

I have just started using Spring Data REST in our Spring MVC application to reduce the work required for having REST HATEOAS support for our API.

This worked almost instantly for top level entities - where we could return all items, PUT/POST new items, or return a specific item by ID.

The issue I'm having now is when trying to follow the link provided to show a collection that is mapped to an entity that I have returned.

I'm having an 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: no Session' being thrown - I presume as it traverses the parent object into the collection (which is lazy loaded).

Googling around for the problem suggests enabling the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - however we are reluctant to enable this for our project, as we have had bad experiences before with that causing dead locks with the database connections.

Can anyone provide a hint as to perhaps a configuration option I might be missing, or something I'm missing from the documentation as to have these links correctly navigate the collection.

Regards,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

You can either enforce eager loading by configarion (e.g. with JPA annotation):

```
@Fetch(value = FetchType.EAGER)
```

or you can specify eager loading per select statement with HQL's `join fetch`

```
select x from X left join fetch x.y y
```

Comment: Setting the collection to Eager loading kind of defeats the purpose of the having the links to collections - when we do a GET (findAll) on Class A, we don't then want to have all Collections of Class B returned (even if it's not returned in the response), as we would effectively end up returning the entire database object graph if we did a FindAll on the top level object.

Answer (score 1):

I have filed a JIRA issue here:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAREST-114

You may go and vote for it.

Comment: Thanks! This appears to be the same problem I was having - I have voted for it. Hopefully it gets fixed soon

Comment: It seems to be working in the 2.0-SNAPSHOT (unreleased yet). You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

For Java based configuration, Add the following dependency according to your hibernate version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add the following configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Registering Hibernate4Module to support lazy objects
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());

        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //Here we add our custom-configured HttpMessageConverter
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```